# Best approach of dealing with Big Data with Rails and MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, bigdata

I'm developing an application on Rails and MongoDB which imports CSVs with hundreds of thousands of records and draw graphs and charts on that data. I have a MongoDB collection of 800K documents, which I wanted to render fully to the front-end and then process the data on the front-end through JS. But the browser hanged while receiving the response.

I'm not sure whether this is the right approach or not. Should the data be streamed to the browser or it's not a good idea to send 800K documents to the browser? If not, I can filter the data on the backend and send the filtered data to the browser.

Looking forward to expert suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use datatables (https://datatables.net/) this will filter and call 10 - 100 records to process on the browser and that is will solve your issue :) 
also for the charts you need to filter the selected data to show on your view :)

Comment: I'm completely familiar with datatables, but the scenario is that I wanted to know if there's a good approach of rendering 800k+ records of data, not just 10-100 records. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: Basically you will have all the record ready but filtered by your rules so all the records will be ready to render  cuz no user will look up 800k+   and no browser will support this much of data .